# FileDownloader and checkbox, download selected items

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

We've created solution where user has a table with files, each entry has checkbox. He can select as many as he like and then click download button.

We are using such resource, it should allow dynamically download, depending on selected items

```
private StreamResource createResource(final IndexedContainer container) {
        return new StreamResource(new StreamSource() {
            @Override
            public InputStream getStream() {

                for (Object o : container.getItemIds()) {
                    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) container.getItem(o).getItemProperty(C_CHECK_BOX).getValue();
                    if (checkbox.getValue()) {
                        selectedFiles.add(o);
                    }
                }
                // do some magic to get stream of selected files


            }
        }, "download.zip");
}
```

The problem is that only second and following click on button is giving expected restults.

It's turns out that FileDownoader is getting resource from server and then it is sending current status of component . It is the reason why first click is giving stale result.

Do you have any idea how to overcome this? Is it possible to force: first update component and then download the resource?

Many thanks 
Pawel

Comment: Try to call setImmediate(true); for CheckBoxes when you create those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CheckBox in Vaadin is non-immediate by default, which means that it won't send a request to server when the checkbox is checked (or unchecked) on the browser. Immediate components send queued non-immediate events also to server but it seems that FileDownloader doesn't cause an event that would send non-immediate checkbox values to server.

The only thing you need to do is to set your checkboxes to be immediate when you create those:

```
checkBox.setImmediate(true);
```

Comment: I've tested it and it works! I solved it also by custom value change listener on checkbox but your solutions is more more elegant. Thanks

Comment: @smolarek999 Yes, adding a ValueChangeListener to it makes a component also immediate in most recent Vaadin versions..

Answer (score 0):

[FileDownloader](http://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.rc1/docs/api/com/vaadin/server/FileDownloader.html) will not suit your needs. As you can read in the documentation:

> Download should be started directly when the user clicks e.g. a Button without going through a server-side click listener to avoid triggering security warnings in some browsers.

That means you cannot dynamically generate `download.zip` file determined by checkboxes values because that requires a trip to server.

You have at least 2 options. Either create new `FileDownloader` and generate new `Resource` `download.zip` every time user make changes to the checkboxes. Or you can add simple `ClickListener` to you Button with this line of code:

```
getUI().getPage().open(resource, "_blank", false);
```

Related: [Vaadin - How to open BrowserWindowOpener from a SINGLE BUTTON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224728/vaadin-how-to-open-browserwindowopener-from-a-single-button/31225019#31225019)

Comment: I don't think this is the problem here. See my answer.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I gave my best guess AFAIU OP . We need to wait for smolarek999 to settle this.

Answer (score 0):

There is also alternative solution to set `checkBox.setImmediate(true);` . It is possible to send current state of all components, just before click, instead of sending each checkBox change.

This solution is based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30643199/1344546

You need to create file downloader button and hide it:

```
Button hiddenButton = new Button();    
hiddenButton.setId(HIDDEN_ID);
hiddenButton.addStyleName("InvisibleButton");
StreamResource zipResource = createResource(container);
FileDownloader fd = new FileDownloader(zipResource);
fd.extend(hiddenButton);
```

Add css rule to your theme

```
.InvisibleButton {
    display: none;
}
```

And then create another button, which 1st update state, and then click hidden button.

```
Button zipDownload = new Button("Download as ZIP file");
zipDownload.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event) {    
          Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript()
         .execute(String.format("document.getElementById('%s').click();", HIDDEN_ID));
            }
        });
```